Integrate GMock with CppUnitTestFramework
I am trying to use the versatile mocking features of GMock within a CppUnitTestFramework unit test project. This post seems to suggest is should be possible, through the use of some interop helper methods, which I have implemented below.
// Interop header
// Call once per test module to set up everything needed by GoogleMock.
void CppUnitTestGMockInterop_Init();

// Call once per test method, to check for GoogleMock messages.
void CppUnitTestGMockInterop_CheckMessages();

/*
 * To use GMock in a unit test class:
 * 1. Include this header file.
 * 2. Add a TEST_CLASS_INITIALIZE method that calls InitGoogleMock.
 * 3. Add a TEST_METHOD_CLEANUP method that calls CheckGoogleMock.
 * 4. Write your tests using Gmock as normal.
 * 5. Profit!
 *
TEST_CLASS(GMockInterop)
{
public:
    TEST_CLASS_INITIALIZE(Initialize)
    {
        CppUnitTestGMockInterop_Init();
    }

    TEST_METHOD_CLEANUP(Cleanup)
    {
        CppUnitTestGMockInterop_CheckMessages();
    }
};
*/

// Interop CPP file
namespace
{
    // Test event listener for use with CppUnitTestFramework
    class CppUnitTestReporter : public EmptyTestEventListener
    {
    public:
        CppUnitTestReporter() : _failed(false)
        {}

        // Helper for converting std::string to std::wstring
        wstring to_wstring(const string& str) const
        {
            wstring output;
            copy(str.begin(), str.end(), back_inserter(output));
            return output;
        }

        // Called after a failed assertion or a SUCCEED() invocation.
        void OnTestPartResult(const TestPartResult& result) override
        {
            // Log this result to the CppUnitTestFramework output
            Logger::WriteMessage(result.summary());

            // Note: You cannot do an Assert directly from a listener, so we
            // just store the messages until CheckGoogleMock() is called.
            if (result.failed())
            {
                _failed = true;

                // Append this result to the running summary
                _failedSummary += result.message();
                _failedSummary += "\n";
            }
        }

        // Clear any previous failures
        void ResetFailures()
        {
            _failed = false;
            _failedSummary.clear();
        }

        // Assert if any failures have been detected. Also resets failures.
        void CheckFailures()
        {
            auto failed = _failed;
            auto failedSummary = _failedSummary;
            ResetFailures();
            Assert::IsFalse(failed, to_wstring(failedSummary).c_str());
        }

    protected:
        bool _failed;
        string _failedSummary;

    } *_listener;
}

// Initialize the Google Mock framework for use with CppUnitTestFramework
void CppUnitTestGMockInterop_Init()
{
    // Avoids calling the function unnecessarily
    if (_listener != nullptr)
        return;

    // Dummy command line parameters (could pass exe path here)
    int argc = 0;
    char** argv = nullptr;

    // Initialize the framework
    InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);

    // We don't want exceptions thrown, regardless what the doc says
    GTEST_FLAG(throw_on_failure) = false;

    // Remove default listener
    auto& listeners = UnitTest::GetInstance()->listeners();
    delete listeners.Release(listeners.default_result_printer());

    // Create and install the new listener
    _listener = new CppUnitTestReporter();
    listeners.Append(_listener);
}

// Prints messages and asserts if any Google Mock messages are found.
void CppUnitTestGMockInterop_CheckMessages()
{
    Assert::IsNotNull(_listener, L"Google Mock framework not initialized by InitGoogleMock()");
    _listener->CheckFailures();
}

With that in place, writing simple unit tests containing a mocked class and method calls seems to work well - as long as there are no EXPECT_CALLs.
// Example tests
TEST_MODULE_INITIALIZE(ModuleInit)
{
    CppUnitTestGMockInterop_Init();
}

TEST_CLASS(WorkingExampleTestClass)
{
public:

    TEST_METHOD_CLEANUP(Cleanup)
    {
        CppUnitTestGMockInterop_CheckMessages();
    }

    class MockTestClass
    {
    public:
        MOCK_METHOD(void, Method1, (int), (const));
        MOCK_METHOD(void, Method2, (int), (const));
    };

    TEST_METHOD(MockedClass_WithMockedMethod_Succeeds)
    {
        MockTestClass mockObj;
        ON_CALL(mockObj, Method2(_)).WillByDefault(Return());
        mockObj.Method2(1);
    }
};

But as soon as I introduce any Expectations on the mocked class, the test fails to complete - there is an internal error thrown within CppUnitTestFramework - outside of the test method itself - which halts the entire test run.
TEST_CLASS(NotWorkingExampleTestClass)
{
public:

    TEST_METHOD_CLEANUP(Cleanup)
    {
        CppUnitTestGMockInterop_CheckMessages();
    }

    class MockTestClass
    {
    public:
        MOCK_METHOD(void, Method1, (int), (const));
        MOCK_METHOD(void, Method2, (int), (const));
    };

    TEST_METHOD(MockedClass_WithExpectCall_CrashesTestProcess)
    {
        MockTestClass mockObj;
        EXPECT_CALL(mockObj, Method1(1)).Times(1); // Expectation will be met
        mockObj.Method1(1);
    }
};

